# Switch neutral on 115VAC, 220VAC 1 and 3 phase mains power

Tags: power, ac, mains

I have an application that will switch primarily motor loads.  It needs to cover US style 115V and both single and three phase 220 and 440 (really up to 460)  Not all cases have a neutral.

I'm in a discussion with another engineer who says that we need a four pole contactor so that we can switch the neutral if it's present.  I've done a number of designs with motor and heating loads and I've never needed to switch the neutral.

Is there a common case or regulation that requires this?

Comment: Ask the engineer whom you are in discussion with why he suggests that.

Comment: The long and meandering answer he gives boils down to “because I’ve always done it that way.”  

I still want to understand if there is a reason that his opinion might be rooted in. I know there are countries that ban grounded neutrals. I can see it making sense as a requirement in those cases.